# ng-messages-include into Ng-View cause "out of memory"

Tags: angular-ui-router, ng-view

I have one page loaded into ng-view in another page, by ui-route.
I need to use one ng-form for the validation, because the "" it's not rendered, but i have notice that with ng-form when i try to go to another page in menù, there is a "out of memory" browser error (Firefox)

```
<body>
    <form name="formRoles" role="form" novalidate>
        <div data-ng-controller="RolesController" class="divPage" >
            <section class="content-header">
                <h1>Ruoli Utente</h1>
                <div ng-form name="myForm">
                    <div class="list-Commands">
                        <button type="button" id="deleteRow" class="btn btn-danger" data-ng-if="idRole != -1"
                            data-ng-click="deleteRow(row)">
                            Elimina</button>
                    </div>
                    <div style="padding-top: 25px" >
                        <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom:0px !important" >
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input class="form-control" name="txtRole" id="txtRole" type="text"
                                    data-ng-model="newRole" placeholder="Nuovo Ruolo Utente" required />
                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                    <a data-ng-click="addRole()" type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Add">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                    </a>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="help-block" data-ng-messages="myForm.txtRole.$error">
                                <div data-ng-messages-include="pages/common/messages.html"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            <section class="content divPage" style="padding-top:0px !important">
                <div class="divObjects dvcollection">
                    <div class="gridStyle  divGrid" data-ui-grid="gridRoles"
                        ui-grid-pinning ui-grid-pagination ui-grid-selection ui-               grid-move-columns
                        ui-grid-resize-columns>
                    </div>
                    <div data-ng-show="showAlert" data-ng-class="{fade:doFade}" class="alert alert-{{alert_type}}">{{errorMessage}}</div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

**Change Title**

SOLVED: the error was present only for the FIRST ng-message in the file that contains the validations messages.....i insert one "default" message and i solve...Why? I don't understand...

```
<div class="messages">
    <div ng-message="default">default</div>
```

Comment: EDIT:
the problem isn't the ng-form, but the ng.message, now i need to find the solution :-)

Comment: Edit2: the error is present only if i try to change page when the form is $invalid, if the form is $valid the error isn't present

Comment: Edit3: with my validation directive the error isn't present, it's present only with "required" validation in page....

Comment: how did you solve this? i have the same problem with out of memory and formvalidation, however i dont use those ng-messages and i still get the leak

Comment: HI, i have posted my solution(not very professional) in the original post :-)